# Espresso get item of recyclerView to do an action

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I'm trying to check the color of the background of an item of my recyclerView, is working, but I do not like the way I did it because I force to click to get it, is there any other way to do it without doing a perform?

```
Uiview.perform(
            RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
                position,
                click()
            )
        ).apply {
            withBackgroundColor(color)
        }
```

And the withBackgroundColor method is :

```
private fun withBackgroundColor(@ColorInt color: Int): Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        return object :
            BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder::class.java
            ) {
            override fun matchesSafely(item: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                return (item.itemView.background as ColorDrawable).color == color
            }

            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said, it works, but I'm forced to do a click to get the item...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `Uiview.perform(...)` call is checking the background color. If I assume `Uiview.perform(...)` does the same as `onView(...).perform(...)`, and returns a `ViewHolder`, then the subsequent `apply` will be "orphaned" - it doesn't do anything else except clicking on the item, and maybe the reason why you're seeing your test is passing.

Otherwise, you can simply create your own custom `RecyclerView` matcher along with your `ViewHolder`:

```
fun <VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> hasHolderItemAtPosition(position: Int, matcher: Matcher<VH>): Matcher<View> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView::class.java) {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("has holder item: ")
            matcher.describeTo(description)
            description.appendText(" at position: $position")
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(view: RecyclerView): Boolean {
            return view.adapter?.let {
                val type = it.getItemViewType(position)
                val holder = it.createViewHolder(view, type)
                it.onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
                return matcher.matches(holder)
            } ?: false
        }
    }
}
```

Then perform your check with background color:

```
onView(your_recycler_view)
    .check(matches(hasHolderItemAtPosition(position, withBackgroundColor(color))))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable I can not get the drawable of the item

Comment: I guess your matcher `withBackgroundColor` is now called, and you get the nullability error. Not all the views have background, some can return null depending on your RecyclerView. You probably want to tweak `matchSafely` function to something like `(item.itemView.background as? ColorDrawable)?.color == resource.getColor(color)` because I don't think `== color` will work, the color must be resolved, not an id reference.

Comment: The thing is that I'd like to get the color of my cardView, is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible as long as it's a resolved color. I misread your code, you annotated @ColorInt so it should be fine. You mentioned about CardView in your last comment, so note that CardView may have different way to set or get background, like getCardBackgroundColor. If that's the case don't forget cast your item view.

Comment: I put on my viewHolder the property of cardView public instead of private so I can access to it, and I put this ```return item.cardView.cardBackgroundColor == ColorStateList.valueOf(
                    color
                )``` but still not passing are you sure this `hasHolderItemAtPosition` is returning the correct item of the recyclerView?

Comment: Yes `hasHolderItemAtPosition` should return item correctly if it finds a match. I don't think the comparison  `cardBackgroundColor == ColorStateList.valueOf(color)` is correct, both are different instance. Maybe try `ColorStateList.getDefaultColor`, otherwise you may need to find help with comparing ColorStateList.

Comment: The thing is I want to check if that specific item has the correct color background on the cardView, so that's why I'm trying to do it like this, because I want to ensure that exactly item has the correct @ColorRes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214653/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-aaron).

Comment: Please help on this :(